# How to serve two different builds of two different repos as per user agent

Tags: nginx

I have two react repos and corresponding builds at `/www/web` and `/www/mobile`

I am trying to serve my static files based on **User Agent**.

By default static files will be served from `/www/web` directory and if it's a mobile device then static files will be served from `/www/mobile`

Following is my nginx `default.conf`

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default off;
    text/html epoch;
    text/css max;
    application/javascript max;
    ~image/ max;
    ~font/ max;
}

map $http_user_agent $ua_device {
    default 'desktop';
    ~*(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ ce|xda|xiino/i 'mobile';
    ~*android|ipad|playbook|silk/i 'tablet';
}

map $ua_device $root_content {
    default '/www/web';
    'mobile' '/www/mobile';
}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    root $root_content;

    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires $expires;
}
```

Now, with this config, web is working fine. But if i check on mobile then I am getting 500 with following error message.

> rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to
> "/index.html"

I have been at this for a long while now, so any pointers would be really great help.

Comment: See if this is helps, from serverfault: https://serverfault.com/a/505099/215387

Comment: @SaurabhPabhare Seems like nginx is unable to find the `index.html` file under your mobile app root (`/www/mobile`). That leads to endless loop trying `/index.html` URI.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thank you. That was the issue. Volume in docker-compose was not getting mounted properly.