# Redirected too many times error on Django React website on Nginx server

Tags: docker, nginx

First, i understand this question has been asked numerous times and i have crwaled through all solutions and i have been unable to solve my issue. I am getting the above error on Dockerized Django and React Application. I am able to access Django API and Admin site over HTTPS with no issue. However when trying to access the React Site i end up getting the above error. Here is my Nginx configs

```
server {
    listen ${LISTEN_PORT_HTTP};

    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

     location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location /api {
       uwsgi_pass               ${APP_HOST}:${APP_PORT};
       include                  /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
       client_max_body_size     20M; 
    }

    location /admin {
       uwsgi_pass               ${APP_HOST}:${APP_PORT};
       include                  /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
       client_max_body_size     20M; 
    }


}
```

I believe the issue is coming from NGINX. If more information is needed i will provide. Could anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks

**UPDATE**
I am realizing the line `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` is the one causing the looping redirects. Upon removing it, i can see the page is bale to load but react static is routing through django's `static` nginx route hence throwing `404` errors as shown on teh screenshot. Can anyone help me how to route reacts static files?

[image]

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine

COPY --from=portfolio-front_react-app /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./default.conf.tpl /etc/nginx/default.conf.tpl
COPY ./uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
COPY ./run.sh /run.sh

ENV LISTEN_PORT_HTTP=8000
ENV LISTEN_PORT_HTTPS=443
ENV APP_HOST=app
ENV APP_PORT=9000


USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static && \
    chmod 755 /vol/static && \
    touch /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    chown nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    chmod +x /run.sh


VOLUME /vol/static

# USER nginx

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

Comment: Your nginx config looks ok. It seems that nginx just can't find an `index.html` file in the `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory, just as it happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69974171/how-to-serve-two-different-builds-of-two-different-repos-as-per-user-agent) (see the discussion under the question). Re-check your docker build configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. While inspecting the said folder i can see ```build``` contents are there including the ```index.html```

Answer (score 0):

I double checked you Nginx configs, I did not see any problem.
It is necessary to explain a little about the project containers. Did you use `Docker-compose` or do you have a separate container for Nginx?
This 404 error is more likely to be related to the container not having access to the `.css` files.
Enter to Nginx container and check if the following path is available inside the container?

```
/static/css/*.css
```

please comment on the answers to my questions.we will examine this issue together. I think I can help. I have just solved a similar case.

Comment: I am copying React build folder contents to ```/usr/share/nginx/html```. I have accessed the nginx container and i can the the build contents are there. I am updating my question to show nginx docker and docker compose configs

Comment: See docker-compose here https://github.com/muteshi/portfolio-app/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 0):

When you build a react application, the default path for the static folder is the root of the build folder. by editing your Nginx config file your static files will be loaded.

```
location ^~ /static {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

The problem is you changed the path of the static folder to somewhere else